# Global Variables Across Files and Folders in PHP

Tags: php, variables, content-management-system, global-variables

I'm building a PHP CMS, but having trouble with variables. I want to be able to have all the variables in an external file, vars.php, and just include that file in every file that requires the variables. The variables all have to do with URLs and folder paths.

The problem I'm running in to is that if I set the variables to full URLs (ex: `$uploadDir = "http://www.example.com/uploads/";`), the scripts don't do what they should. Same thing if I use absolute paths (ex: `$uploadDir = "/uploads/";` or `$uploadDir = "/full/server/path/uploads/";`).

If I use full URLs, it seems like it at least tries to work, but doesn't. If I use the full server path or absolute path, I get some error about that path not being allowed. The files are all stored in `/edit/` or `/edit/(sub-folder-name)/`, if that helps.

I'll look around for some code examples where I would be using this, and update this post ASAP.

Thanks.

UPDATE:

Some of the variables from this code snippet aren't included, just didn't think I should post a huge PHP script.

Example of `$pageDir`:

```
// The below 2 lines are actually in vars.php, which is included in this file.
$pageDir = "http://www.example.com/edit/pages/";
$url = "http://www.example.com/";

if ($_POST["page"] && $execute == TRUE) {
    $live = $_GET["p"] . ".php";
    // The below line is how this used to be set up.
    // $handle = fopen("pages/$page", "w");
    // The below line is how the new version should be set up.
    $handle = fopen("$pageDir/$page", "w");
    fwrite($handle, $_POST["page"]);
    fclose($handle);
    // The below line is how this used to be set up.
    // echo("<p>Page successfully saved. <a href=\"../$live\" target=\"_blank\">Click here to view this page.</a></p>\n");    
    // The below line is how the new version should be set up.
    echo("<p>Page successfully saved. <a href=\"$url/$live\" target=\"_blank\">Click here to view this page.</a></p>\n");    
    $execute = FALSE;
}
```

Comment: Your use of URLs instead of server paths is a bit confusing for opening and saving files. (And this [might help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4369/how-to-include-php-files-that-require-an-absolute-path).)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use URLs for file-system functions. That will make them do a HTTP request, not load the files from the filesystem.

Also if you use `/absolute` paths, then that will refer to the filesystem root, not to your webservers [document root](http://google.com/search?q=DOCUMENT_ROOT). PHP filesystem functions do not operate on virtual path names, but on the real system file structure.

You can however use:

```
 $pageDir = "/edit/pages/";
 readfile("$_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT]/$pageDir/$page");
```

That's probably what you want.

Other caveats: despite the meme, there is nothing wrong with global vars. You should however not swamp the shared scope with dozens of them. Instead define an array like `$dir["page"]` for folders. Or `define()` constants.

Comment: "There is nothing wrong with global vars *when used with caution and appropriate consideration*." The problem isn't with the global variables themselves, but with the coding practices (or lack thereof) that usually accompany poor implementation.

Comment: I think it's mostly that all code executes within the 'global' scope, and the unavoidable leftofters from multiple template-like php scripts, paired with overly generic var names. Might not be a problem in OPs case, but less is sometimes more.

Comment: It's entirely possible to do everything in the global scope if everything is appropriately segregated. I know I've got some code in my (getting more distant) past that I go back and review and I'm still amazed it worked as expected, *somehow*. With something like a CMS, hopefully everything is planned out and segregated appropriately for the style of programming being deployed. Some practices are potentially less (significantly) error-prone than others.

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do in this snippet is to

- open an URL with fopen (this works in php, but your provider might disable url_fopen, see http://phpsec.org/projects/phpsecinfo/tests/allow_url_fopen.html)
- Write something to it.

Since it's an HTTP URL, you can't write anything to it (you can send POST request some way, but I'm sure you don't want that)

You have to use actual file system paths for file system operations (like storing something in a file ;) )

To do that you might want to use the $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] variable, or you can do a trick:

`$my_dir = dirname(__FILE__);`

The variable `$my_dir` then will contain the directory name the current script is in.

Also, you might want to use some database like MySQL or MongoDB (very, very different things) to store contents in. If you don't know these, you should read a few examples, they're great. ;)