# variables not working through include pages

Tags: php, include

Ok... I have a ton of different pages all which have the same little block of code. Up to now, I have been updating the `$max = 150;` over all the pages manually as the number changes. So I tried making a max.php with this single line in it and referencing it from all the others.

However.. here's a problem I have...

**/vars/max.php**

```
$max = 150;
```

**/inc/changes.php**

```
include 'vars/max.php';
echo $max;
```

Returns 150

**/update/updatepage.php**

```
include 'vars/max.php';
echo $max;
```

Returns 0

So.... It works on one page, but not on another. If I change **max.php** to this...

**/vars/max.php**

```
<?php
    $max = 150;
?>
```

then the **/inc/changes.php** returns 0, and **/update/updatepage.php** returns 150.

### Any ideas why?

I have already tried changing it to $GLOBALS["max"] but it's the same.

Is there a better way to do this so I only have to update the value in one place? I don't want to use a mysql database as my hosting company is a bit iffy with how many connections are in use.

Thanks for any help you can give.

Comment: Are you expecting the changes you make to `$max` to persist between requests?

Comment: You are saving `$max = 150;` but you are including `rises.php` so do your `rises.php` file have `max.php` included?

Comment: what is the relation between `max.php` and `rises.php`?

Comment: use DEFINE, for constants

Comment: @Mr.Alien Sorry... That was a typo. I have updated to show that they are both referencing `include 'vars/max.php';`

Comment: @Amir Sorry... That's a typo.. rises.php should actually be max.php in my code.. I've updated it now.

Comment: @Cully Path are different too

Comment: The first version of `max.php`, without `<?php ?>` tags, **should not work at all.**

Comment: @deceze I agree... but it does. I'm just trying to get it constant between all my files. I thought someone might have come across this before... or maybe I'm making this overly complicated.

Comment: Directories are different, use complete paths or provide correct relatives path. This should already work then

Comment: Let's put it this way: **it does not work without `<?php ?>` tags!** Where you *think* it works it probably does for different reasons. It's only correct *with* `<?php ?>` tags.

Comment: @deceze Ok, but it's getting the 150 from the max.php file without the `<php ?>` tags being there. I don't understand it and that's why I'm asking on here. I know it's getting it from that file because when I change the number on ONLY that file, it picks it up on my `/inc/changes.php`.

Comment: @ØHankyPankyØ If I put `include 'http://www.website.com/vars/max.php';` then it does the exact same thing. Is that what you meant?

Comment: @Mr.Alien If I put `include 'http://www.website.com/vars/max.php';` then it does the exact same thing. Is that what you meant?

Comment: @Cully Path is making troubles for you here and for the absolute path, read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4369/how-to-include-php-files-that-require-an-absolute-path

Comment: @Mr.Alien Thank you so much for that link.. it solved my problem. I just put `include $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].'/vars/max.php';` and it works on all of my files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the file path over here is resulting to this

Try using absolute paths for your includes, answer over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4369/how-to-include-php-files-that-require-an-absolute-path) will help you

Declared Variable Path - `/vars/max.php`

Including In Files Path

- `/inc/changes.php`
- `/update/updatepage.php`

Comment: Thank you... I tried changing to `include 'http://www.website.com/vars/max.php';` and it didn't work, but then as per your link, I changed it to `include $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].'/vars/rises.php';` and it works perfectly!

Comment: Also I'd like to add that **max.php** uses the `<?php ?>` tags with this. I'm not sure how it 'worked' without.

Answer (score 0):

Try to include like this

```
include 'vars/rises.php';
echo $max;
```

in the pages that you want to access the $max variable...you are only including the 'rises.php' but your max value is given at the 'rises.php'

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you're getting 0, but I have run into problems before when multiple files try to include the same file in one request.  Try using `include_once "vars/max.php"` instead.

That way it only gets added to the include path once, and you shouldn't have any more conflicts.

Comment: I've just changed them all to `include_once 'vars/max.php';` but there is no change.

Comment: in that case it seems like the problem may be the path you're using.  In your post, you specify "/vars/max.php" as the path to the file.  Try writing that into your code exactly.  Instead of "vars/max.php" (without a leading forwardslash), use "/vars/max.php" (with a leading forwardslash)

Comment: I tried with both a forwardslash and without... same result on both files. Putting `include 'http://www.site.com/vars/max.php';` also didn't work, BUT it's now working when I put in `include $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].'/vars/max.php';`

Comment: okay. it's important to note something about file paths here.  if you put a "/" in front of your path, you're comuncating that the folder/file is at the root of your file system.  $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] provides the actual root to the file system, which is why it's working.  In php, the include function looks for files using an acutal file path.  The Http path won't work.

Comment: Thanks - yeah I'm quite a beginner with this. I didn't realise you should use the root url given in `$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] ` and I assumed that http paths would work. I need to hit the books.

Answer (score 0):

Problem could be the updation of variable through script. You probably setting $max=0; otherwise it has to be null.

My point is, If it a constant deal it as a constant, use php define function. Otherwise your scripts will be modifying it and as it is global you will be stucked to figure out where it has been modified.

Comment: it's not a constant. It will be changing every few days. 6 or 7 different pages use this variable and I have been manually updating each page to date. I want to be able to update one place which updates all of these pages...

Comment: so what use, define('MY_MAX' , $someValueFetchedFromSomewhere);