# What is the scope of imports in PHP?

Tags: php, include, scope

I have three files at my server:

```
foo.php
assets/bar.php
assets/qux.php
```

`foo.php` includes `bar.php`, and `bar.php` includes `qux.php`. The code of `foo.php` is shown below:

```
<?php
    include_once("assets/bar.php");
?>
```

How should `bar.php` include `qux.php`? Should it use `include("qux.php")` or `include("assets/qux.php")`?

Comment: includes get interpreted in the scope they are called in.

Comment: Have you tried it? Which one worked?

Comment: Asking is one way of getting the answer, but trying some experimenting (add some echo statements and what not) would likely be a better learning experience.

Comment: You should use `include (__DIR__."/qux.php");`

Comment: @Gordon The "duplicate" doesn't talk about the paths at all.

Comment: It's pretty much explained in the PHP Manual: Files are included based on the file path given or, if none is given, the include_path specified. If the file isn't found in the include_path, include will finally check in the calling script's own directory and the current working directory before failing. If a path is defined — whether absolute (starting with a drive letter or \ on Windows, or / on Unix/Linux systems) or relative to the current directory (starting with . or ..) — the include_path will be ignored altogether. See http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php

Comment: @Juhana I have tried both, but they both don't work. I wanted to be sure I was using the right one before I spend my time at (unnecessary) debugging.

Comment: @Juhana it's good enough for me since it references the PHP manual which the OP doesn't mention at all to have consulted prior to asking. But anyway, I'll reopen it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It actually should use `include("assets/qux.php")`. The path to included files is dynamic; it depends in this case on `foo.php`.

If you are going to include `bar.php` from multiple directories, it is probably better to use absolute paths.

So, there are two ways to "chain-include" files in PHP:

### Way #1 (Dynamic relative path)

```
include("assets/qux.php");
```

### Way #2 (Absolute path)

```
$ROOT = realpath($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]);
include("$ROOT/assets/qux.php");
```

[As seen here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4369/how-to-include-php-files-that-require-an-absolute-path/4385#4385)

Answer (score 2):

If they are in the same directory, then it is simply:

```
include("qux.php")
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you haven't modified your includes path, `include_once('qux.php')` should work fine.