# PHP Fata error: require(): Failed opening required 'rep registration.php'

Tags: php, require

I get the following error message:

**[24-Nov-2013 10:59:00 Europe/Stockholm] PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required 'repregisration.php' (include_path='.:/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.10/lib/php') in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/reg4event/register.php on line 46**

The script **register.php** looks like this where **line 46** exists:

```
// Check if SESSION is SET
if ( (isset($_SESSION["RegType"])) && (isset($_SESSION["eventId"])) ) {
    // Check if it is a Rep Registration or a Guest Registration
    if ( $_SESSION["RegType"] == "rep" ) {
        // The Registration if of type "rep", require the repregistration script
        require "repregisration.php";

    } elseif ( $_SESSION["RegType"] == "guest") {
        // The Registration if of type "guest", require the guestregistration script
        require "/snippets/guestregistration.php";

    } else {
        // Neither of "rep" or "guest" was set in the $_SESSION["RegType"], hence header back to index.php page
        header("Location: index.php");
        exit();

    }
} else {
    header("Location: index.php");
}
```

The **repregistration.php** file contains this:

```
<?php
// Check which STAGE the Rep registration process is in
if ( !isset($_SESSION["RegStage"]) ) {
    // Include the Registration script
    require "/pages/repform.php";

} elseif ( isset($_SESSION["RegStage"]) == "review" ) {
    // Include the Review script for the registration to confirm their details
    exit("RegStage Review has not been created!");

} elseif ( $_SESSION["RegStage"] == "confirmed" ) {
    // Include the Confirmed information
    exit("RegStage Confirmed has not been created!");

} else {
    header("Location: index.php");
    exit();
}
?>
```

Why do I get the error message?

Comment: All the files in the same directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your file name is `repregistration.php` but your are including `require "repregisration.php";` - there is a spelling mistake in your include line.

Comment: Thank you! No matter how often I look for spelling errors, I seem to always miss them. :)

Answer (score 0):

It cant find the file. Try using `require_once('...');` and try using Fully qualified paths. [How to include PHP files that require an absolute path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4369/how-to-include-php-files-that-require-an-absolute-path)

It is simply looking in the wrong spot for the file.

Comment: Does the system not by default use the path from the script which is used and relates from that path?

Comment: Yes usually, but you can't count on that it depends on Operating system, and where the script is run from.