# include not work (PHP)

Tags: php

i have strange problem with include commnad

my files structure

```
/index.php
/files/init.php
/files/db.php
```

and sources of this files

**index.php**

```
<? 
include ('files/init.php');
?>
```

**init.php**

```
<?
include ("db.php");
?>
```

Source from **db.php** is not executing..  NOW if i rename file **db.php** to **db2.php** and rename it in init.php NOW IT WORKS
there is some php cache or what ?  i dont understand it.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's `include ("files/db.php");`. On a side note, you should **not** use short open tags `<? ?>`, it will save you some pain when moving to other environments.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to include PHP files that require an absolute path?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4369/how-to-include-php-files-that-require-an-absolute-path)

Comment: No it is different problem. read my answer conflict filename DB.php from PEAR.

Comment: The answer listed there is somewhat "universal" and way better than your methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

conflict filename DB.php from PEAR.

**DB.php** from PEAR is included instead of your **"db.php".**.

So use filename other than "db.php".

EDIT or use include with **DIR** macro

Comment: Same issue on "config.php"

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<?php
include ("db.php");

?>
```

or using `./`

```
<?php
include ("./db.php");

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The included files are resolved according to the entry point (here `index.php`).
Moreover, `require` is better is the file *MUST* exist.

**index.php**

```
<?php require 'files/init.php'; ?>
```

**files/init.php**

```
<?php require 'files/db.php'; ?>
```

---

**Update 1:** As suggested by @Darsstar, here is an example using `__DIR__`:

**files/init.php**

```
<?php require __DIR__.'/db.php'; ?>
```

---

**Update 2:** Maybe you should consider [`PSR-0`](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-0.md) or [`PSR-4`](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/proposed/psr-4-autoloader/psr-4-autoloader.md) to deal with file inclusion.

Comment: You might want to add an example using `__DIR__`

Comment: ok it works, but why if i only rename file db.php to db2.php  now work this      <?php require 'db2.php'; ?>
how can it be possible that it works with different file name. That's what I want to know. In other project i am using it and it works.

Comment: @PepíkSamků Are you sure that there is no other `db2.php` in the include path?

Comment: i make this simple example. There is only this 3 files. It is some bug or i dont know.

Comment: @PepíkSamků it's just impossible. A typical [user error](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_error). Make sure to show hidden files. It's just tiresome to help troubleshoot such trivial things.

Comment: http://us3.php.net/get_included_files can be used to see which db2.php was included. Like @HamZa said, this should be a user error.

Comment: OMG I know..

PEAR DB.php  something like shadowing variables so there shadowing included files 

thanks for that get_included_files();