# How to call a file outside public_html within the domain directory using php

Tags: php, cpanel

I have a domain that has a subdomain. I want to call a file in the subdomain folder but apparently my subdomain folder is outside the public_html directory. Here is what i tried but nothing is happening.The subdomain folder is subdomain.

```
<?php
include("subdomain/conn.php") // location of the file in the subdomain
?>
```

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4369/how-to-include-php-files-that-require-an-absolute-path

Comment: Try include('../subdomain/conn.php');

Comment: @Robot70 still not working

Comment: Can you give the arrangement of folders?

Comment: why not use the base path, the entire server path to the subdirectory folder?

Comment: The public_html folder and subdomain folder are in the main root so the subdomain folder is not inside the public_html folder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is usually most helpful to include with an *absolute path instead of a relative path*. There are two typical ways to approach this. This example will work with the following directory structure, as you did not provide yours:

```
 +var
 |+www
  |+public_html
   -index.php
   |+subfolder
    |somescript.php
  |+subdomain
   |conn.php
```

**1)** In your index.php file, declare a constant corresponding to the absolute path to the public_html directory

```
define('APPLICATION_BASE', __DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
```

Then later use this as the prefix for all includes, and append the path relative to there:

```
include APPLICATION_BASE . '../subdomain/conn.php';
```

This option works well for most general purposes, allowing you to quickly include most any file relative to the front-controller/index file

**2)** Alternately, if you are not using a uniform index file and do not have a consistent point of reference reliable enough to always be included, you would apply a similar approach and *include based on an absolute path from the file including it*. This usually indicates you are lacking good application structure, but for a quick and dirty app or legacy code that was not structured with a definitive single point of access, this is often necessary. In the case where you had to include a file from `somescript.php`, and did not reliably arrive there from `index.php`, you would probably do something like this:

```
include __DIR__ . '/../../subdomain/conn.php';
```

It should be noted that this works in a pinch, but it is far from optimal, and you should try to massage your application toward the first approach if at all possible. Using a consistent point of entry will save you a lot of guesswork later when debugging, as you will know all files are included based on relevance to a single origin directory, and it will keep error messages and logging a lot cleaner and more readable over time, which in turn will save you a lot of time debugging.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it yet but it should work.

```
$public_htmlUrl = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
$outsideUrl = "../".$public_htmlUrl;
$file = outsideUrl."subdomain/conn.php";
include($file);
```